# How to Visualize Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the tools that provides a function to visualize SQL Server Stored procedures?

Comment: What do you mean by "visualize" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, editing or creating them, SQL Server Management Studio will allow you to do this, and comes with SQL Server. SSMS will also allow you to debug stored procedures. Visual Studio, with SSDT (SQL Server Development Tools) installed, will allow you to do this too, and actually does a much better job of allowing you to debug stored procs. Debugging stored procs in SSMS has always been problematic for me.

SSDT can be installed for VS 2010 or VS 2012. In fact, you don't even need to own Visual Studio to install SSDT. If you install it without VS, it will install a VS shell, and allow you to execute the full functionality of SSDT, without having Visual Studio installed.